# Electron | TypeError: "x" is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a simple electron app that opens a browser window to a url of a webpage.

I import my stuff using
`const { BrowserWindow, app, MessageChannelMain } = require('electron');`

I create my window on `app.on("ready")` using `window = new BrowserWindow({ ... });` and everything works fine.

When I try to create a `MessageChannelMain` using `const {port1, port2} = new MessageChannelMain();`, I get the error:
`TypeError: MessageChannelMain is not a constructor`.

Full code:

```
function init_window(){
    if ( mainWindow == null ) {
        mainWindow = create_window();
        load_window(); // calls mainWindow.loadURL(myURL);
        
        const {port1, port2} = new MessageChannelMain();
        port2.postMessage({ test: 21 })
        port2.on('message', (event) => {
            console.log('from renderer main world:', event.data)
        });
        port2.start();

        mainWindow.webContents.postMessage('main-world-port', null, [port1])

        mainWindow.on('closed', function(event) {
          mainWindow = null;
        });

        mainWindow.webContents.on("did-fail-load", function(event) {
            
        })
    }
}

function create_window() {
    return new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        darkTheme: true,
        webPreferences: {
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
    });
}
```

When I `console.log(MessageChannelMain);` I get undefined.

At the same time, I get other errors when I try to use some electron stuff on the preload script:

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
  'electron',
  {
    doThing: () => ipcRenderer.send('do-a-thing')
  }
)
```

Here I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'exposeInMainWorld' of undefined`

Comment: Where exactly have you included this line? `const { BrowserWindow, app, MessageChannelMain } = require('electron');` It does not appear in your code sample.

Comment: I require electron like that at the top of my ``app.js`` file, which is the main entry point @camslice